# Writing from PIG to MongoDB - error 2116 - mongodb schema not found

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig

I am using Hadoop on Windows Server 2008 - Hortonworks distribution
We are using PIG and trying to write the data into MongoDB; I am not able to read or write to the MongoDB; not sure what the issue we get an error 2116 which states that the mongodb schema is empty

Command to read -

```
register 'D:\hdp\pig-0.12.1.2.1.1.0-1621\lib\mongo-hadoop-core-1.2.0.jar'
register 'D:\mongo-hadoop-2.2-1.2.0\mongo-hadoop-2.2-1.2.0\mongo-hadoop-1.2.0.jar'
register 'D:\mongo-hadoop-2.2-1.2.0\mongo-hadoop-2.2-1.2.0\mongo-hadoop-pig-1.2.0.jar'
register 'D:\hdp\hadoop-2.4.0.2.1.1.0-1621\lib\mongo-2.6.1.jar'
set mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution false;
set mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution false;
SET mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs false;
SalesLoading = load 'mongodb://localhost/benvenuedb.SalesData' using com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader();
store SalesLoading into 'mongodb://localhost:27017/benvenuedb.SalesData1' using com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage();
```

Error Messages

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2116: 
<line 5, column 0> Output Location Validation Failed for: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/benvenuedb.SalesData More info to follow:
The value of property mongo.pig.output.schema must not be null

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias salesLoading
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1637)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:577)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1093)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.plan.VisitorException: ERROR 2116: 
<line 5, column 0> Output Location Validation Failed for: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/benvenuedb.SalesData More info to follow:
The value of property mongo.pig.output.schema must not be null
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOStore.accept(LOStore.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:64)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.walk(DepthFirstWalker.java:53)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator.validate(InputOutputFileValidator.java:45)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.compile(HExecutionEngine.java:303)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.compilePp(PigServer.java:1382)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1307)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1299)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$400(PigServer.java:124)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1632)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value of property mongo.pig.output.schema must not be null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:971)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:953)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoStorage.setStoreLocation(MongoStorage.java:249)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:68)
    ... 20 more
```

I have issued netstat -an to see the open ports
The local address is 10.69.148.89; I do not see the port 27017 open in this IP; however 127.0.0.1 has 27017 open. There is something simple we are overlooking.

Need some help; we have spent over 2 days with no resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in writing to MongoDB from PIG especially when you use Hortonworks windows distribution. I have broken this into Three steps;

1. Write to HDFS filesystem as a json file using JSONStorage( );
2. Move the HDFS file to windows filesystem
3. Load the json file into MongoDB

I am open if anyone has attempted this in a different way

Comment: Could you file an issue on that?  I'm going to be focusing on the Pig support over the next few weeks.

Comment: @evanchooly, I think the issue is already logged, that is what I understand from the google searches. Again this is an issue only on the windows platform (hortonworks)

Comment: OK.  Great.  I'm hoping to start tackling the backlog of pig issues next week.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the property it says is missing?

```
The value of property mongo.pig.output.schema must not be null
```

Comment: I am not using java; just plain pig, is there a way we can set it from pig directly?